# Controller background image not working

Tags: html, css, airconsole

The background-color works fine, but I can't get the background image to work. It just shows the background colour. The picture is in the same folder as the controller file. I'm using Unity. [Picture of the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCQmc.png). Thank you!

controller.html

```
<head>    
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(background.png);
        background-color: white;
         }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image file name is correct?
You could add a div and style that with a background instead of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets for the controller need to be in Assets/WebGLTemplates/AirConsole.
I assume your controller (the file you're working on) is not in that folder, but somewhere else in the project.
There is a controller file in the WebGLTemplates folder, but that one updates automatically to mirror the one linked in the AirConsole object in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotation marks into `url("background.png")`